# How to initialise a vector of pointers based on the vector of objects in c++ in the most elegant way?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, initialization

If one has a vector of objects like:

```
vector <Obj> a;
```

What whould be the best way to create a vector of pointers to the objects in vector a?:

```
vector <Obj*> b;
```

Comment: Which version of C++ ? C++11, C++14, C++~17 ? And why not a vector of smart pointers ?

Comment: Since C++11  you can use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (i.e.: vector<Obj*> b { new Obj(), obj_ptr, ... })

Comment: Be careful doing this.  If `a` ever has to allocate new storage you'll end up with a vector full of dangling pointers.

Comment: @krzaq's answer is great, but I'd just like to point out here that this is a fragile situation.  The pointers in `b` can be rendered invalid by almost any insertion or deletion into `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
// if b is empty (this will append to the end of b)
b.reserve(a.size()); // optional, but a good habit
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), [](Obj& o){ return &o; });
```

​
alternatively

```
b.resize(a.size());
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), [](Obj& o){ return &o; });
```

Alternatively, you could use `boost::transform_iterator` to initialize `b` directly:

```
auto tr = [](Obj& o){ return &o; };
std::vector<Obj*> b(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(a.begin(), tr),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(a.end(), tr)
);
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that `b` should be empty before this call. In case the OP thinks that they must be `b.resize()` first

Comment: well `reserve` could not hurt and resize would probably do something OP would not want to. ..

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I'm not sure how you deduced that op would like to `resize`, but edited :)